# Updating a data.frame with an observeEvent

Tags: r

People!

If i have the following data frame:

```
observeEvent(input$pesquisa,{

    query <- glue(
      "select 
      cod_ordem_producao as ORDEM,
      dim_ext_tubo as DIAMETRO,
      esp_par_tubo as PAREDE,
      cod_aqa as AQA,
      tmo_ciclo_plan as CICLO,
      dth_criacao_reg as DATA,
      dsc_aco as GRAU,
      val_lim_escoamento as LE,
      val_tensao_residual as TR
      from
      QT_QTS.PLA_ORDEM_PRODUCAO
      where DIM_EXT_TUBO = {as.numeric(input$diametro)}
      and esp_par_tubo = {as.numeric(input$parede)}
      and tmo_ciclo_plan = {as.numeric(input$ciclo)}
      and dth_criacao_reg between DATE '{as.character(input$dates[1])}' and DATE '{as.character(input$dates[2])}'
      and VAL_LIM_ESCOAMENTO != 0
      order by DTH_CRIACAO_REG desc")

    df <- dbGetQuery(
      connection_reportUser,
      query
    )    

    df    <-------------- HERE IS THE SAVED VALUES TO THE DATA FRAME---------------
    valor_grau <- df$GRAU
})
```

And, next, I use another observeEvent:

```
observeEvent(input$pesquisa, {

      insertUI(
        selector = "#pesquisa",
        where = "afterEnd",
        ui = selectInput(
          "grau",
          label = "Grau:",
          choices = valor_grau
        )
      )
    })
```

Explaining:
I search in a database these values and save into a data.frame (called "df") . When I search for it (with the input's and clicking on the button "pesquisa"), a new field called "Grau:" appear for the user, with new selectable values.

How can I update the "df" with the value from the second input? (in that case, the input from the "insertUI" called "Grau:"

---------------- EDITED ------------------------

In my UI code, i have a:                          `DT::dataTableOutput("contents2")`

In server side, i have:

```
output$contents2 = DT::renderDataTable({
      tabela_saida})
```

My first observeEvent is that described above, and save into my *df*, than, i have a:

```
tabela_saida = df
```

The second observeEvent, should update a value called `GRAU` in my *tabela_saida*.
The third observEvent, should update *AQA*...and so on.

The last of all, should expose the datable updated with all the new values and make a search in my database.

Comment: Hey! Not sure if I understood the question. I think you need just one `observeEvent` for `input$pesquisa`. After that you are going to create an `observeEvent` to `input$grau` and then you are going to update the `df` based on the `grau` choices. Where are you using the `df` object?. Can you provide a reproducible example as mentioned in (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I have already edited. Can you help me now, plz?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to update your `data.frame` according to an entry (`grau`). To do this, you can create an `eventReactive` that will execute your query. Within `eventReactive` you need to check if the user has already selected something in `input$grau`.

This is a way to do this:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    actionButton(inputId = "pesquisa", label = "pesquisa"),
    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.pesquisa > 0", uiOutput("grau")),
    DT::DTOutput("contents2")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  create_df <- eventReactive(input$pesquisa,{

    ## Your query about here
    ## ...
    ##

    df <- data.frame(x = round(rnorm(100), 2), grau = rpois(100, lambda = 10))
    grau_values <- unique(df$grau)

    if(!is.null(input$grau)){
      grau_input <- input$grau

      df <- subset(df, grau %in% grau_input)
    } 

    return(list(df = df, grau_values = grau_values))
  })

  output$grau <- renderUI({
    grau_values <- create_df()$grau_values

    selectInput(inputId = "grau", label = "Grau:", multiple = TRUE, choices = grau_values, selected = NULL)
  })

  output$contents2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    df <- create_df()$df

    datatable(df, rownames = FALSE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I hope it works!

Comment: Man, thanks for the help, but it did not work. =(
When i run another query, it just not update the new DF

Comment: Did you use this template? Did you find the same problem using it? You must to provide a minimum example with a piece of your dataset and a minimum shiny app otherwise you will not find a solution to this problem.